# Global.asax parent application and child application

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm working on some legacy code right now and I'm trying to move the Global.asax file up to the parent application and it will manage all of the children applications. Currently we have a Global.asax file in all of the children apps (bad).

When I try removing the Global.asax file from the child application, it does not find the parent application's Global.asax file unfortunately. Therefore I cannot stay authenticated within the child app. I was wondering if there is an easy fix to this.

Structure:

```
parent app 
  files...
  childapp
    files..
    global.asax
  global.asax
```

I want the childapp to find the parent's Global.asax file.

Thanks guys!

EDIT:

Global.asax

(This is identical in the parent and child apps)

```
protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void Session_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        public void Application_AuthenticateRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            String cookieName = FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName;
            HttpCookie authCookie = Context.Request.Cookies[cookieName];

            if (null == authCookie)
            {//There is no authentication cookie.
                return;
            }

            FormsAuthenticationTicket authTicket = null;

            try
            {
                authTicket = FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(authCookie.Value);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //Write the exception to the Event Log.
                return;
            }

            if (null == authTicket)
            {//Cookie failed to decrypt.
                return;
            }

            //When the ticket was created, the UserData property was assigned a
            //pipe-delimited string of group names.
            String[] groups = authTicket.UserData.Split(new char[] { '|' });

            //Create an Identity.
            GenericIdentity id = new GenericIdentity(authTicket.Name, "LdapAuthentication");

            //This principal flows throughout the request.
            GenericPrincipal principal = new GenericPrincipal(id, groups);

            Context.User = principal;

        }

        protected void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void Session_End(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void Application_End(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
```

Comment: Can you show what the .asax file looks like for one or 2 of the files..?

Comment: they are identical. I've now moved the global.asax.cs file to the App_Code folder and I am trying to inherit that in to the child application, good or bad idea? It still isn't working so i'm guessing bad idea...

Comment: if they are all the same then why are you not using one global.asax what is the reasoning for having so many..?

Comment: That's a great question. I did not write the original code. I'm trying to move it to one Global.asax file right now as you have suggested :). However I am having authentication issues inside of the children app when I don't have a local Global.asax file

Comment: perhaps you should move the code for your ActiveDirectory / LDAP Authentication code into a CommonFunctions .cs file create your own library.. if not it truly sounds like a namespace issue you are having in regards to the application finding the correct .cs or if asax file. If you move that file to a folder you need to change or update the namespace of that file to reflect it's location. if the code is all the same in all the files..that tells you right there that you need to have it in one place and come up with a method or Interface to reference it from all the other forms ..

Comment: that's like writing the same 50 lines of code 5 or 10 times over and over again..

Comment: what does the namespace look like for that file you have uptop

Comment: namespace FormsAuthAd on all of the files

Comment: well you should do as Sacrilege has suggested

Answer (score 0):

As others have stated there is probably a better way to accomplish your goal but strictly speaking, if I understand your question correctly, it should be possible.

The class that each of the Global.asax inherits from must be in a shared assembly. Then you can change the markup for each of the Global.asax files to inherit from that shared class.

```
<%@ Application Inherits="MySharedGlobal" Language="C#" %>
```

You can remove the code behind for each of the application (both parent and children) but the Glabal.asax file must remain.

*You could move the shared code into a base class just as easily that each application object inherits from in the code behind. This would allow you to still add application specific logic as needed.*

**Now, you could also create an IHttpModule an place the shared code in it and when loaded in the parent application will also be loaded in the child applications (via config inheritance).**

*Edit:*
If am understanding you correctly, you want to run the same code in each application without having it copy and pasted over and over again. If you need to have actual "applications" for each nested site then that code has to run multiple times. That doesn't mean it can't be shared however.

A simple way to do that is to create class that implements `IHttpModule` and add that to your parent application config file. In the 'Init' method you can hook into the `AuthenticateRequest` event and run the same code you posted from there instead and remove it from the Global.asax code behind in each child application.

Another way to accomplish it would be to create an implementation of `HttpApplication` that hooks into the same event (just like it does now). You can then place the shared code in the base class and each class in the Global.asax code behind file would inherit from that. Then you could remove the code from each Global.asax code behind file.

If you create the `IHttpModule` the Global.asax files could be removed. Otherwise, they would need to stay.

Comment: I tried moving it in to the App_Code folder and inheriting from that class in the App_Code folder, and that did not work. Is that what you are talking about by "Base Class"?